# ARCore: 3DCoordinates of all points in a camera frame

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

This is my first time with android development.
I wanted to get the 3D coordinates of all the points in the current camera frame and store this information along with the image. I came across anchors where you can get position of the anchors wrt to the camera, but you have to tap the screen for that. So I was wondering if there is some way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: There is a call to get the translation values for the camera frame, so just add those to each point in a copy of the original model. Don't know what you mean by image, but if its the textures on the model, then you have it somewhere already...

Comment: @YinOrYan So i'm not looking to add any ar element in the camera frame, I just want the 3D coordinates of each pixel and save this depth image. (Sorry beforehand I'm not familiar with the terms that ar community uses)